# Backup Wine configurations in Linux

Tags: linux, backup, wine, foobar2000

I am using Foobar2000 under Wine in Linux with a specific setting for its default user interface (colors, a msstyle theme) which is rather difficult to make each time with `winecfg`.

On a new Linux system I have simply copied the entire `~/.wine` folder from a previous installed system. It works, but I think that is not the best solution.

What specific file/s must be saved in order to make a backup of that `winecfg` configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wine moved away from a configuration file since June 2005 and uses its
emulated Windows registry instead.

You will find the WINE settings in the emulated registry at
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine`.

When you copied the entire `~/.wine` folder, you also copied the registry.

Reference:
[Useful Registry Keys](https://wiki.winehq.org/Useful_Registry_Keys).